# Remote Desktop triggers a loud Beep on local machine - how to shut it up?

Tags: remote-desktop

When I remote desktop into a server, I get a loud beep coming out of my local machine whenever certain messageboxes pop up.

(An example is to search for something in the Event Log - when the search finds no results, I get a message box accompanied by a loud beep)

Annoyingly, the beep still happens even if I have sound turned off locally or the volume right down - it seems to be hooking in to some low level OS-beep mechanism.

Any way to turn it off?

Comment: Switch to 64bit Windows - it has no traditional system beep ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [disabling the internal PC speaker driver, beep.sys](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/configuration/how-do-i-stop-windows-2000-from-beeping-.aspx).

Comment: I'm seeing this solution all over the internets but doesn't fix it for me. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Slightly more subtle, you can disable it at the registry level:

http://learnwithharv.com/blog/remote-desktop-beep-server-2008/